Inconsistent execution times for stored procedure
I have a stored procedure that runs daily. Most days it completes in about 20 minutes, some days it takes an hour. I'm trying to find the cause so I can get it to be more consistent. I looked for other jobs/processes that could be running at the same time and competing for resources, but did not see anything promising.
Ran BlitzCache. First result is Plan Cache Instability with 100% plans created in the past 24 hours. But the server was just patched and rebooted last night so I think that is to be expected.
The second result is Plan Warnings (warning detected in execution plan). Checked the Execution Plan and saw a recommendation for a missing index. It wants an index on PaidDate and then Include all the other columns in the table. I find the sql recommendations for indexes to be hit/miss, plus this database is a backup from a vendor and I do not have direct control to add indexes at will. Also, as long as I'm not clearing the plan cache I'm doubtful that a missing index would cause this type of inconsistency.
Third is Non-SARGable queries. I've included what I believe is the most resource intensive part of the query. The final step is to INSERT into a table from the temp table. There is a CASE statement, but we use CASE statements a lot and do not have this kind of variability in other stored procedures.
              DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #PPNUnpivotCCO;
      SELECT 
       CCOMemberID = xw.CCOMemberID, 
       MemberID = e.PrimeID, 
       RateCD = e.RateCode, 
       ContractServiceAreaCD = e.ContractServiceAreaCode, 
       EligCat = e.EligCat,
       ContractRateAMT = Convert(decimal(15,2),e.ContractRate), 
       Method = e.Method, 
       CCOPremiumAMT = Convert(decimal(15,2),e.PremiumAmount), 
       ---Medical
       Medical_PartnerCD = med.PartnerCD, 
       Medical_PartnerNM = med.PartnerNM, 
       MedBaseAmt = Convert(decimal(15,2),e.MedBaseAmt), 
       MedRiskRateAmt = Convert(decimal(15,6),e.MedRiskRate), --Numeric length extended to 6 past the decimal C.S.
       MedAdjAmt = Convert(decimal(15,2),e.MedAdjAmt), 
       AdminWHMedAmt = Convert(decimal(15,2),e.AdminWHMed),
       StrategicWHMedAmt = Convert(decimal(15,2),e.StrategicWHMed), 
       CommunityWHMedAmt = Convert(decimal(15,2),e.CommunityWHMed), 
       ReserveWHMedAmt = Convert(decimal(15,2),e.ReserveWHMed),
       MedFinalAMT= Convert(decimal(15,2),e.MedFinal),
       ---Mental Health
       Behavioral_PartnerCD = beh.PartnerCD, 
       Behavioral_PartnerNM = beh.PartnerNM, 
       MHBaseAmt = Convert(decimal(15,2),e.MHBaseAmt),
       MHRiskRateAmt = Convert(decimal(15,6),e.MHRiskRate), --Numeric length extended to 6 past the decimal C.S.
       MHAdjAmt = Convert(decimal(15,2),e.MHAdjAmt),
       AdminWHMHAmt = Convert(decimal(15,2),e.AdminWHMH), 
       StrategicWHMHAmt = Convert(decimal(15,2),e.StrategicWHMH), 
       CommunityWHMHAmt = Convert(decimal(15,2),e.CommunityWHMH), 
       ReserveWHMHAmt = Convert(decimal(15,2),e.ReserveWHMH), 
       MHFinalAmt = Convert(decimal(15,2),e.MHFinal), 
       ---NEMT
       NEMTBaseAmt = Convert(decimal(15,2),e.NEMTBaseAmt), 
       NEMTWithholdAmt = Convert(decimal(15,2),e.NEMTWithhold),
       StrategicWHNEMTAmt = Convert(decimal(15,2),e.StrategicWHNEMT), 
       CommunityWHNEMTAmt = Convert(decimal(15,2),e.CommunityWHNEMT),
       NEMTFinalAmt = Convert(decimal(15,2),e.NEMTFinal),
       ---Dental
       Dental_PartnerCD = den.PartnerCD,
       Dental_PartnerNM = den.PartnerNM,
       DenBaseAmt = Convert(decimal(15,2),e.DenBaseAmt),
       DenRiskRateAmt = Convert(decimal(15,2),e.DenRiskRate), 
       DenAdjAmt = Convert(decimal(15,2),e.DenAdjAmt),
       AdminWHDenAmt = Convert(decimal(15,2),e.AdminWHDen),
       StrategicWHDenAmt = Convert(decimal(15,2),e.StrategicWHDen), 
       CommunityWHDenAmt = Convert(decimal(15,2),e.CommunityWHDen), 
       ReserveWHDenAmt = Convert(decimal(15,2),e.ReserveWHDen), 
       performanceWHDenAmt = Convert(decimal(15,2),e.performanceWHDen), 
       DenFinalAmt = Convert(decimal(15,2),e.DenFinal),
       MCOTaxAmt = Convert(decimal(15,2),e.MCOTax),
       HRAAmt = Convert(decimal(15,2),e.HRA),
       RevenueRAEFinalAMT = COALESCE(e.MedFinal, 0) + COALESCE(e.DenFinal, 0) + COALESCE(e.MHFinal, 0), 
       MemberMonth= CASE
                        WHEN e.RateCode COLLATE database_default IS NULL THEN 0
                        WHEN e.RateCode COLLATE database_default IN (
                                SELECT RateCD
                                FROM Reference.Reference.Rate r
                                WHERE r.ExcludeFromMM = 'Y')  THEN 0
                        WHEN e.Prorate > 1 THEN 1
                        ELSE ROUND(e.Prorate, 5)
                         END , 
       BenefitMonth = DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(e.BenefitBegin), MONTH(e.BenefitBegin), 1) , 
       StartDT = Convert(date,e.BenefitBegin)  , 
       EndDT = Convert(date,e.BenefitEnd), 
       PaidDT = Convert(date,e.PaidDate),
       PremiumPaymentNotificationID
        INTO #PPNUnpivotCCO
--select e.*
FROM VendorDB.dbo.Allocation e
    INNER JOIN Reference.Reference.CCOIdToMemberID xw                   -- only active members (solves the issue of multiple MemberId for a single COMemberid
                    ON xw.CCOMemberID = e.ccoMemberID
                    AND xw.MemberID COLLATE database_default = e.PrimeID
                    AND xw.ActiveFLG = 1
    LEFT JOIN Reference.Reference.Rate r---updated to left join, for some of the kickers, we do not have the rate codes set up in reference. 
                ON e.RateCode COLLATE database_default = r.RateCD
     LEFT JOIN Reference.Reference.Partners Med
                ON (
                    e.MedPlan COLLATE database_default = Med.PartnerNM
                    OR
                    e.MedPlan COLLATE database_default = Med.PartnerAlt1NM
                    OR
                    e.MedPlan COLLATE database_default = Med.PartnerAlt2NM
                    )
                    AND Med.ActiveFLG = 1       
     LEFT JOIN Reference.Reference.Partners beh
                ON (
                    e.MHPlan COLLATE database_default = beh.PartnerNM
                    OR
                    e.MHPlan COLLATE database_default = beh.PartnerAlt1NM
                    OR
                    e.MHPlan COLLATE database_default = beh.PartnerAlt2NM
                    )
                    AND beh.ActiveFLG = 1   
     LEFT JOIN Reference.Reference.Partners den
                ON (
                    e.DenPlan COLLATE database_default = den.PartnerNM
                    OR
                    e.DenPlan COLLATE database_default = den.PartnerAlt1NM
                    OR
                    e.DenPlan COLLATE database_default = den.PartnerAlt2NM
                    )
                    AND den.ActiveFLG = 1   

        
WHERE 1=1
    and Convert(date,e.PaidDate) >=  Convert(date,DateAdd(Year,-2,GETDATE())) ---Only pulling paid the last 2 years
    
;


   DELETE Enrollment.PremiumCCOMemberMonth where PaidDT >=  Convert(date,DateAdd(Year,-2,GETDATE()));

    
        
INSERT INTO Enrollment.PremiumCCOMemberMonth
(CCOMemberID, 
 MemberID, 
 RateCD, 
 ContractServiceAreaCD, 
 EligCat, 
 ContractRateAMT, 
 Method, 
 CCOPremiumAMT, 
 Medical_PartnerCD, 
 Medical_PartnerNM, 
 MedBaseAmt, 
 MedRiskRateAmt, 
 MedAdjAmt, 
 AdminWHMedAmt, 
 StrategicWHMedAmt, 
 CommunityWHMedAmt, 
 ReserveWHMedAmt, 
 MedFinalAmt, 
 Behavioral_PartnerCD, 
 Behavioral_PartnerNM, 
 MHBaseAmt, 
 MHRiskRateAmt, 
 MHAdjAmt, 
 AdminWHMHAmt, 
 StrategicWHMHAmt, 
 CommunityWHMHAmt, 
 ReserveWHMHAmt, 
 MHFinalAmt, 
 NEMTBaseAmt, 
 NEMTWithholdAmt, 
 StrategicWHNEMTAmt, 
 CommunityWHNEMTAmt, 
 NEMTFinalAmt, 
 Dental_PartnerCD, 
 Dental_PartnerNM, 
 DenBaseAmt, 
 DenRiskRateAmt, 
 DenAdjAmt, 
 AdminWHDenAmt, 
 StrategicWHDenAmt, 
 CommunityWHDenAmt, 
 ReserveWHDenAmt, 
 performanceWHDenAmt, 
 DenFinalAmt, 
 MCOTaxAmt, 
 HRAAmt, 
 RevenueRAEFinalAMT, 
 MemberMonth, 
 BenefitMonth, 
 StartDT, 
 EndDT,
 PaidDT,
 PremiumPaymentNotificationID
)
       SELECT CCOMemberID, 
             MemberID, 
             RateCD, 
             ContractServiceAreaCD, 
             EligCat, 
             ContractRateAMT, 
             Method, 
             CCOPremiumAMT, 
             Medical_PartnerCD, 
             Medical_PartnerNM, 
             MedBaseAmt, 
             MedRiskRateAmt, 
             MedAdjAmt, 
             AdminWHMedAmt, 
             StrategicWHMedAmt, 
             CommunityWHMedAmt, 
             ReserveWHMedAmt, 
             MedFinalAmt, 
             Behavioral_PartnerCD, 
             Behavioral_PartnerNM, 
             MHBaseAmt, 
             MHRiskRateAmt, 
             MHAdjAmt, 
             AdminWHMHAmt, 
             StrategicWHMHAmt, 
             CommunityWHMHAmt, 
             ReserveWHMHAmt, 
             MHFinalAmt, 
             NEMTBaseAmt, 
             NEMTWithholdAmt, 
             StrategicWHNEMTAmt, 
             CommunityWHNEMTAmt, 
             NEMTFinalAmt, 
             Dental_PartnerCD, 
             Dental_PartnerNM, 
             DenBaseAmt, 
             DenRiskRateAmt, 
             DenAdjAmt, 
             AdminWHDenAmt, 
             StrategicWHDenAmt, 
             CommunityWHDenAmt, 
             ReserveWHDenAmt, 
             performanceWHDenAmt, 
             DenFinalAmt, 
             MCOTaxAmt, 
             HRAAmt, 
             RevenueRAEFinalAMT, 
             MemberMonth, 
             BenefitMonth, 
             StartDT, 
             EndDT,
             PaidDT,
             PremiumPaymentNotificationID
           
       FROM #PPNUnpivotCCO
  
                    

Fourth is regarding implicit conversions.

The column [xw].[MemberID] has a data type of varchar which caused
implicit conversion on the column [e].[PrimeID].

They are both varchar, so I'm guessing the implicit conversion is a result of the COLLATE needed because this database has a different collation than the other databases on the server.
Does any of this look like the probable cause or do I need to dig in other places?

The first thing I’d suggest is to not use the plan cache for this. Since you’re on 2019, you should be using Query Store. It will help you track important factors, like execution plan changes and wait stats. That will help you explain the variance in execution time.

Can you please provide the actual execution plan via Paste The Plan? It's hard to tell root performance issues without it. What I will say, is I'm sure 20 minutes can even be further optimized magnitudes faster, and all the ORs in your join conditions are potentially hurting you too.

@ErikReasonableRatesDarling - I should be using that. I had some space limitations before that prevented me from using it. And I've done so long without it I forget it's there. Will implement.

@Don I'm a little confused. The code in your post that you claim is the most resource intensive, is not in the code of the execution plan you linked.

@J.D. - Sorry was trying to be concise and ended up being confusing. I updated to the sql code to include the entire query and loaded the most recent execution plan for it. https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=rJrcLTQG1g

(1) Day over day, is the volume of data being processed always the same? (2) "Different collation" is (to me) a really bad sign--particularly since you are writing from [your DB's collation A] to [tempdb's collation B], and then back. Seems like a lot of CPU work going on that you cannot measure. This is a total guess... but if you can "blow the smoke away" (by lining up collations), it might be easier to see the real problem. (3) Oh, and there are two queries in there. Does execution time rise/fall proportionally between them, or is only one the source of the extra processing time?

@PhilipKelley - (1) The table it's pulling from is about 102 million rows. I believe it steadily increases over time. I'll track its growth on a daily basis. Next time it has a long run I'll check and see if there was an abnormally large change in the row count. (2) The source db is provided by a third party and I can't change the collation in which it is provided. I may be able to change it in our test environment and save the execution plan. Then when I see another bad run in prod I can bring it over to test and do that same thing for comparison purposes.

@PhilipKelley - (3) I do not have any data from a bad execution to compare. On a normal run the 1st query is the longest, but on a bad run perhaps it's the 2nd query that is the issue. I just enabled query store on that db so I can capture data about the bad run.

To rule out differing collations as the problem, can you set up a temporary SQL instance installed with matching collation, and run tests on that? (Perhaps similar to nuking it from orbit, but then you'd be sure.)

@PhilipKelley - Unfortunately I have not been able to recreate the error in test yet. However, I have the job on a schedule so thought I'd change the collation on the db just in case I get lucky. Changed the collation through ssms and t-sql. Verified it changed but it is still giving me collation errors. Wonder if I need to truncate that table and then import the data into it with the new collation set.

I had collation issues once, years and years ago. I recall it was really fussy work, and difficult to reset. We ended up having to drop and rebuild the SQL instance to resolve things. This, perhaps obviously, is biasing my advice here... again, I am suggesting this might be the source of your problem, but I have no absolute knowledge or proof.

@PhilipKelley - Thanks for the help. Could not get the collation changed correctly. Deleted the data, changed the collation on the db and verified. Reloaded data into db with updated collation and still got an error about mismatch in collation. But I think I figured out the root cause so not a big deal.

Figured it out. I think the number of new records is fairly consistent, but the query uses PaidDT and the number of records per PaidDT is heavily skewed.

